# How to get the data stored in Apple Watch file system?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm making an independent app on apple watch platform to record some user data which is going to be saved in the apple watch file system. But I don't know how to pull these data out to my PC. Is there any method to pull data out from apple watch?

Comment: you need to save it on icloud then you will extract that data from there